# LiveDataReactiveStreams: converting Flowable to LiveData doesn't work

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-java2, android-architecture-components, android-livedata

I'm trying to convert a Flowable into LiveData and observing it in the activity. My Flowable is emitting values with a constant delay ,
but the LiveData which i'm converting this Flowable to, is not at all receiving any values in its observer. I have created a sample code to 
demonstrate the problem

Activity

```
    public class MyrActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);
            MyViewModel myViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(MyViewModel.class);
            myViewModel.init();
            myViewModel.getListLiveData().observe(this, new Observer<List<String>>() {
                @Override
                public void onChanged(@Nullable List<String> strings) {
                    Timber.d("value received in live data observer: %s", strings);
                    // This callback never get called
                    for (String string : strings) {
                        Timber.d(string);
                    }
                }
            });

        }
    }
```

ViewModel  class

```
     static class MyViewModel extends ViewModel{
            LiveData<List<String>> mListLiveData;
            PublishProcessor<String> mStringPublishProcessor = PublishProcessor.create();

            public void init() {
                mListLiveData = LiveDataReactiveStreams.fromPublisher(mStringPublishProcessor.toList().toFlowable());

                // This is to trigger the mStringPublishProcessor on constant intervals
                Observable.interval(0,5,TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                        .map(aLong -> {
                            Timber.d("value emitted: ");  // this log is showing as expected
                            mStringPublishProcessor.onNext("Value "+aLong);
                            return aLong;
                        }).subscribe();
            }

            public LiveData<List<String>> getListLiveData() {
                return mListLiveData;
            }
        }
```

Now , in my activity I can see only the logs from the `Observable.interval`

```
     com.example.app D/MyActivity$MyViewModel: value emitted: 
     com.example.app D/MyActivity$MyViewModel: value emitted: 
     com.example.app D/MyActivity$MyViewModel: value emitted: 
     com.example.app D/MyActivity$MyViewModel: value emitted: 
     com.example.app D/MyActivity$MyViewModel: value emitted: 
     com.example.app D/MyActivity$MyViewModel: value emitted:
```

Why the LiveData observer never received any values from the Flowable?

as per the documentation of LiveDataReactiveStreams.fromPublisher

> Creates an Observable stream from a ReactiveStreams publisher.
>        When the LiveData becomes active, it subscribes to the emissions from the Publisher.

Comment: if this is api call , why we have to use this instead of normaly using setValue when onNext called

Comment: `LiveDataReactiveStreams.fromPublisher` will do the same thing for you. You don't have to subscribe each observable and manually convert it into a `LiveData`. using `setValue` (Provided you are handling the error properly since `LiveData` does NOT handle errors and it expects that errors are treated as states in the data that's held)

Comment: do you have example , iam still confuse with this , tkanks

Comment: I think you have understood it in a wrong way. It's not a replacement for Rx. It's just a utility class which helps to convert an Rx Observable to LiveData and vise versa

Comment: Please refer the [Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/LiveDataReactiveStreams) for more details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`.toList()`](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/to.html) will map the return only after `onComplete()` call. In your example, the completion is never called.

Comment: Ohh yea... My source was a hot observable which never calls `onComplete` and stays active all the time. Didn't notice it. Thank you!!

Comment: can we use LiveDataReactiveStreams when call api , do you have example for this